# Reactivity of Silicon

Tags: reactivity

$$\ce{SiO2 + 2C ->[2200°C] Si + 2CO}$$([Ref](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon#Production))

In this reaction, C is apparently [displacing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_displacement_reaction) Si from SiO2. Does this mean C is more reactive than Si? But Si is more electropositive than C. What is the explanation for this? Where will Si be placed in the reactivity series?

Comment: It depends. What temperature?

Comment: Reactivity is not a thing at all. Also, CO2 does not form in your reaction, nor does your reference say so.

Answer (score 1):

Let's compare the boiling points of these substances. Silicon is boiling at $2355°$C. Carbon is boiling at $4200°$C. $\ce{SiO2}$ is boiling at $2590°$C. So at $2200°$C, $\ce{CO}$ is the only gaseous substance. Whatever the change of enthalpies or the electronegativities, its formation is favored.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a reaction that happens. That is a summary of a set of reactions that happen, at (at least 2) different equilibria and different temperatures.

The direct reactions are as follows, at "steady state" solids if not specified:

$$\ce{2SiO_2 + SiC <-> 3SiO(g) + CO(g)}$$
$$\ce{SiO_2 + Si(l) <-> 2SiO(g)}$$
$$\ce{SiO(g) + SiC <-> Si(l) + CO(g)}$$
$$\ce{SiO(g) + 2C <-> SiC + CO(g)}$$

There is no reasonable answer to your question, because that reaction does not happen in a single step, it is not displacing anything. Though, the fact that you have to pour a spectacular number megawatts into the process for it to continue does suggest that $\ce{Si}$ is not "more reactive" though.